# How to find the if an object has passed a certain regions between frames in OpenCv

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, object-detection

please can you look at the following picture [Basketball detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dwFv.jpg)
I am tracking a ball(A) using a stationary camera, and I have it's coordinates. I have also managed to use the same camera to detect a basketball hoop using object detection, then I calculated 2 regions: 1 above the hoop(B) and the other below the hoop(C). I want to be able to tell if the ball has passed between these 2 regions(B and C) between frames, so I can detect a shot made.
I know I should use an IF statement to decide this but how do I capture the position of something(the ball) in one frame and it's position in the other frame? If you do not quite understand my question please can you look at this implementation I am trying to reproduce:https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/basketball-goal-detection-rnn-stephan-janssen/

Edit:
I managed to get the centre coordinates of the ball using:

```
c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
M = cv2.moments(c)
xa = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
ya = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
radi = radius
```

For the ROI:
The coordinates of the hoop are:

```
if object_name == "hoop":
 ymin = int(max(1,(boxes[i][0] * imH)))
 xmin = int(max(1,(boxes[i][1] * imW)))
 ymax = int(min(imH,(boxes[i][2] * imH)))
 xmax = int(min(imW,(boxes[i][3] * imW)))
```

xmin and ymin are the coordinates of the top left corner of the region.
xmax and ymax are the coordinates of the bottom left corner.

To calculate the rectangle on top of the hoop I used:
cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmin,ymin-60), (xmax,ymax-60), (10, 255, 0), 2)

To calculate the one at the bottom I used
cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmin,ymin+30), (xmax,ymax+30), (10, 255, 0), 2)

So, what I am asking:

1. How can I use these coordinates/rectangles to know when xa and ya(coordinates of the ball) are within those regions.
2. How can I capture the position of the ball in one frame and see how different they are in the next frame?

Currently this is what I am using to read the frame if it helps?:

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(VIDEO_PATHS)
while(video.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = video.read()
```

Comment: Track the x/y position relative to the centroid from your object (ball here) along the video and check against your ROI as you said, you can get the ball position from a few forms, but mostly the linkedin article give you a good north. Also, update your question with a few examples to see how far you are and we can help you better.

Comment: Hi Gabriel, I just made the edit, please can you tell me if I need to add more stuff. Thank you :)

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay, didn't check your in the machine yet, but think the regions as your "i'm in/ i'm out", if you have the x/y coords of the ball and the ROI of the hoop then it's just a matter of math to see if the ball coord fall into those values, for joining the two ROI's i'd approach as a slide window with some flags with respect of in/out probabilities of a valid shot